# How Do I Build a Mailto Hyperlink Column in a Cognos Report?

Tags: reporting, cognos

I am building a report which shows a list of users that are out of compliance due to not meeting a training deadline.

The queries that show and filter the data have been built and I have verified the correct information is showing in my list.

I now want to add some "action items" to the grid.  The first item I am working on is a "Hyperlink Button" that will launch an email to the out-of-compliance user.  The email should be addressed to this user, have a hard coded subject, and contain a body that has hard coded text with some data points from the query.

The "List Column Body" for the button column has its "Source Type" property set to "Report Expression"

Expression:

```
'mailto:'+ [ExceptionsByOrgQuery].[Email]  + '?subject=Compliance%20Exception&body=Hello%20' + [ExceptionsByOrgQuery].[Full Name - First Last] + '%2C%0D%0A%0D%0AYou%20are%20overdue%20for%20training.%20%20Please%20complete%20the%20following%20training%20as%20soon%20as%20possible.%0D%0ATraining%20course%3A%20' + [ExceptionsByOrgQuery].[Activity Name] + '%0D%0ADue%20Date%3A%20' + [ExceptionsByOrgQuery].[Date]
```

All the variables that are used to build the link are in the query and should be matching up to the items for that row, correct?

For some reason I am getting an error when trying to validate this report.

The error I receive is:

```
RSV-VAL-0032 The following expression is not valid:...expression here... If the item exists in a query but is not referenced in the layout, add it to a property list. CRX-API-0005 An error ocurred at or near the position '11'. The variable named 'ExceptionsByOrgQuery].[Email]' is invalid.
```

I'm more unsure what the first part of the error means.  The email variable is not shown in the grid, but it is part of the query.  I can add it to the grid and verify that it is in the query, but I do not want that value to display in the report (nor do I want the variable [Full Name - First Last] to be displayed; it's just for the greeting in the email).

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
The List is populating from a query called [ReportQuery]
It contains the following data items.

- [Name]                <- [Compliance].[Employee].[Last Name] + ', ' +[Compliance].[Employee].[First Name]
- [Organization]        <- set([Dimensional View].[Organization].[Organizations] -> ?org?)
- [Registration Status] <- [Compliance].[Fact Organization Due Exception].[Registration Status]
- [Title]               <- [Compliance].[Employee].[Title]
- [Activity Name]       <- [Compliance].[Activity].[Activity Name]
- [Due Date]            <- [Compliance].[Time].[Date_US]
- [Email]               <- [Compliance].[Employee].[Email]
- [Name - First Last]   <- [Compliance].[Employee].[First Name] + ' ' +[Compliance].[Employee].[Last Name]

(the first item is the label and the second portion is expression that is used to make the data item)

EDIT 1 (from melee's suggestions):
I've attempted the method you describe, but am now seeing this error: RSV-VAL-0032 The following expression is not valid: ''. If the item exists in a query but is not referenced in the layout, add it to a property list. CRX-API-0005 An error ocurred at or near the position '21'. The variable named '[ReportQuery].[Email]' is invalid.

I did a query regarding this error and saw that that the List object needed to have the properties that I used in the mailto in a "Properties" property.  Defining this property allowed me to select items from the query.  I did this with mailto, but it appears to be not matching up values to the correct row; ie. I've set the subject argument on the mailto to be the user's name ([ReportQuery].[Name]) and it doesn't match up with what is shown on the row in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you're going to need to follow these steps to get this to work properly - your syntax, concatenation, and everything else looks great - just a little tweaking of the process and you'll be good to go.

1. Drag an HTML item into a list report.
2. Select it - under the properties pane, change "Source Type" to "Report Expression" (defaults to Text, which is of no use to us right now)
3. Double click the HTML item and create the mailto anchor You can use your code sample, but make sure it is validating correctly before closing. it should, at its simplest, look something like: `'<a href="mailto' + [Data Item] + '">'` - important; do not close the anchor tag at this point.
4. Unlock the report (padlock on the top)
5. Add another HTML item to the cell (it will look like there's two HTML items in the same column) and set it to "Report Expression"
6. Double click the HTML item and add static text/close the tag. For example: `Email Me</a>`

Run the report and you should have links that you can click (tested as working on 8.4.1)

Comment: Any reason this does not work: '<a href="mailto:' + [ReportQuery].[Email] + '">Email Me</a>' ? ie Why do I have to create the second HTML Item?

Comment: I've attempted the method you describe, but am now seeing this error:  RSV-VAL-0032 The following expression is not valid: '<a href="mailto:' + [ReportQuery].[Email] + '">'. If the item exists in a query but is not referenced in the layout, add it to a property list. CRX-API-0005 An error ocurred at or near the position '21'. The variable named '[ReportQuery].[Email]' is invalid.

Comment: Well, first things first - what are your queries and their data items?

Comment: Correct, I'm no longer getting an error, but the data isn't matching up.  If the name column has "Paula Person" the custom html column has "John Doe".  It seems like it is a favoring one name more than others.  I see one name more common than others, but one other appears randomly.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to check your aggregate functions on your data items. If they're set to automatic, it can create problems. You can troubleshoot this issue further by bringing all of your data items to the List report (you can remove them later) and seeing if there's anything amiss.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try viewing the query as tabular data to see what's going on.

Comment: It seems like I have an odd issue with my organization item.  We're trouble shooting it, but it doesn't relate to this issue (thankfully!).  You're answer is 100% correct.  I verified it on a test of this grid (when figuring out the org. issue) and didn't cause issue in another list that I made.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out! By the way, I said two separate HTML items because for some weird reason I did that before. You actually might be able to get away with not having the second one there. Good luck on your delve into BI.. I'm in the same boat as you!